# How can I set a default value on ReferenceManyField component?

Tags: react-admin

I'm rendering a ... which resource is "Users", so always is calling this ReferenceManyField on  but sometimes "User" don't have "Name", and I want to display some default  if "User" don't have name, I did't find any solution for this problem, sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the contents of the 'record' field before passing it to your components:

```
<ReferenceManyField reference="Users" target="id" >
  <SingleFieldList>
    <FormDataConsumer>
      { ({ formData, dispatch, record, ...rest }) => {

          const defValues = { Name: 'MyName', Param1: 'Value1', Param2: 'Value2' }
          const newRecord = { ...defValues, ...record }
          const params = { record: newRecord, ...rest }

          return (<TextField source="Name" {...params} />)
        }
      }
    </FormDataConsumer>
  </SingleFieldList>
</ReferenceManyField>
```